# Configuring iPod on Linux

Tags: file-transfer, music, ipod

I use Fedora 13 and very recently I brought a new Apple iPod shuffle. I would like to know whether I can transfer music into my iPod without using iTunes. I tried using gtkpod and RhythmicBox, but that is of no avail.

Comment: Right. What goes wrong then, because the iPod I have just shows itself as a USB device and Rhythmbox seems perfectly able of handling it. Of course, I run Rockbox on it, which is a lot less picky of where MP3 files should be stored and what they should be named...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about state now but Apple is know for play of cat and mouse. You may find one day that update of software of iPod had broken its compatibly with Linux by completly redesigning its format.

Until one day someone reverse engeneer the new format and supplied patches for projects. It lasts as long as Apple would not decide to switch format again.

In short: iPod is not the best player for Linux enthusiast but when you have it you may be able to use it.

PS. Also Banshee have iPod support

Comment: Apple doesn't really play cat and mouse games.  However, they're very clear on what they do or do not support, and pay no attention to what they don't.  For example, they don't support jailbreaking iOS, so all such is done through security holes, which Apple fixes when it finds them, and Apple doesn't care what updates may do to jailbroken iDevices.  Bear in mind that current iTunes should work with most iP*s out there, and current iP*s should work with lots of generations of iTunes, so they don't have all that much flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your IPod should work with gtkpod which uses the libgpod library, like almost every linux application.

Have a look at http://gtkpod.wikispaces.com/Supported+iPods for your model.
After that, have a look at the "Getting Started" Page of the gtkpod project:
http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Getting_started

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [rebuild_db](http://shuffle-db.sourceforge.net/), a Python (2.x) script that updates the iPod Shuffle's database. You just have to put the audio files somewhere in your iPod, then run the script and the iPod Shuffle will be able to play the audio.

[Their website](http://shuffle-db.sourceforge.net/) has detailed instructions and tells which iPod Shuffle models are supported.